# jquery error left of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

i keep getting this error on mys site http://www.revolvercreative.com.au/gallery.html#
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null** 
cant figure out what this means.

```
    subArrowXPos = curMenu.parent().position();
    subArrowDestWidth = curMenu.parent().width();
    destArrowX = subArrowDestWidth / 2 - parseInt(subArrowUp.css('width'), 10) / 2;

        subArrow.jacked({
            left: subArrowXPos.left,
            width: subArrowDestWidth,
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });

        subArrowUp.jacked({
            left: destArrowX
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
}

function checkMenuWidth() {

    var logoWidth = $('.logo').width() + 40;
    var availableWidth = contWidth - logoWidth;
    var menuWidth = $('.ddsmoothmenu').width();
    var mainMenu = $('nav #smoothmenu');
    var dropDown = $('nav form');
    var arrow = $('#submenuArrow');



    if (availableWidth >= menuWidth) {
        mainMenu.css({
            'visibility': 'visible'
        });
        dropDown.css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
        arrow.css({
            'display': 'inline'
        });
    } else {
        arrow.css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
        mainMenu.css({
            'visibility': 'hidden'
        });
        dropDown.css({
            'display': 'inline-block'
        });
    }

}
```

any ideas please ?, js novice here ;)

Comment: `curMenu.parent().position()` is returning `null`. Trying to access the `left` parameter of the result is causing the error.

Comment: Try console logging `subArrowXPos`.

Comment: `curMenu` is set to `$('#smoothmenu #active a')` but I can't see any element with `id='active'`

Answer (score 0):

when you are using jquery make sure you have the selector inside the $() and change these lines

```
subArrowXPos = curMenu.parent().position();
subArrowDestWidth = curMenu.parent().width();
```

to this

```
subArrowXPos = $(curMenu).parent().position();
subArrowDestWidth = $(curMenu).parent().width();
```

Answer (score 0):

curMenu.parent().position() is returning null so subArrowXPos is null. So when you try to access the left property, you will get an error. Check how you are defining curMenu, I bet you will find an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that 'subArrowXPos' is null.

Try to change this:

```
subArrowXPos = curMenu.parent().position();
```

by this:

```
subArrowXPos = $(curMenu).parent().position();
```

If it does not fix the issue, please do this on top of your code :

```
console.log(curMenu);
```

And copy paste the content of your javascript console.